# Портретная ориентация в сборке WebGL Unity

Tags: unity3d, webgl

Пробовал сделать портретную ориентацию в игре под WebGL в Unity, но столкнулся с проблемой - ориентацию экрана по умолчанию выбрать в player preferences под WebGL нельзя. Пробовал решить это через редактирование кода в html-файле собранного приложения:

```
    <script>
    screen.lockOrientation("portrait");
    </script>
```

Плюс в коде самой игры:

```
{
#if UNITY_WEBGL && !UNITY_EDITOR
Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
#endif
}
```

Ни один из способов не работает(первый так вообще все сломал). Может быть еще есть какие-то способы?